# Get coordinates of element inside dropdown

Tags: javascript

I got a dropdown list and want to show some information on hover for each element.
I tried something like this, with `item` being the list elements and `infobox` being a `fixed` positioned `div` providing the information:

```
item.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
   e.stopPropagation();
   if (e.target === e.currentTarget) {
     dropdownInformation.category_id = selectOptions.category_id[index];
     document.getElementById("infobox").style.left = e.target.getBoundingClientRect().x + "px";
     document.getElementById("infobox").style.top = e.target.getBoundingClientRect().y + "px";
     }
});
```

How'd I get the correct coordinates of the right border of the list entries?

[image: Dropdown list]

(Yes, I did read several other questions regarding that topic on SO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this seems to do the trick. I needed to add / subtract the width / height of the parent element and the scrollbar.

```
item.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.target === e.currentTarget) {
        dropdownInformation.category_id = selectOptions.category_id[index];
        e.target.style.borderLeft = "2px white solid";
        document.getElementById("infobox").style.left = 
          (e.target.getBoundingClientRect().x +
          e.target.getBoundingClientRect().width + 
          (e.target.parentElement.offsetWidth - 
          e.target.parentElement.clientWidth)) + "px";

        document.getElementById("infobox").style.top = 
          (e.target.getBoundingClientRect().y - 
          (e.target.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().height / 2)) + "px";
    }
});
```